# Company wants back a miscalculated salary

Tags: salary, germany

As a little bit of background, I have been working in Germany for about a year now. It is a startup company with less than 40 people.

Last December I received €1.7k more than my usual salary. I reported this to my immediate manager (who is also one of the partners and top management). He said sometimes it happens at the end of the year, and it is ok. I waited for a couple weeks and there were no follow ups. So I used the money.

Today, my manager told me that it was actually a mistake at somewhere and I should pay the money back.

What options do I have? Is it possible to reject such a demand?

There is a law for pretty much everything in Germany. Is there a law or at least a widely accepted rule for such a situation?

---

To be clear, my manager is a really cool guy and he was also very uncomfortable while giving me these news. So I really don't want a problem with him.

Comment: You might ask to reimburse in several months

Comment: We have a [number of questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=overpaid) on this topic, most of them closed because they ask for legal advice. The short answer is that yes, you do have to repay them, and you should never have spent the money in the first place.

Comment: @DavidK I have missed the the keyword `overpaid`. Thanks for that. In my defence, I am unfamiliar with the system here, therefore asked my manager and received the answer it's ok.

Comment: Does your company pay bonuses at years end (Jahresendprämie/Weihnachtsgeld)? Are those 1700€ before or after reductions? What does your salary statement(Lohnabrechnung) say as to why you got this extra money?

Comment: @Dulkan The company paid a bonus last year around May, not the end of the year. I just checked my salary statement and it doesn't say anything about the extra money. I guess I will just pay it back in several months.

Comment: So, your salary statement says, you got your usual monthly salary and nothing else, but your bank statement says you got 1700€ more than on your salary statement?

Comment: @Dulkan Exactly. Looks weird, right?

Comment: It not being part of your salary statement also opens the can of worms of taxes that need to be payed, if you were to keep it.

Comment: In Germany it is common to have a 13th month paid at Christmas  maybe to OP thought this was the case

Comment: @Neuromancer If this was case, it would appear on the salary statement.

Comment: @Dulkan and who reads every  line of there statement each month or even reads it at all :-)

Comment: Do you have your managers comment that you should keep the money in writing? If yes, great, if not, then make sure you get something like that in writing next time.

Comment: @Neuromancer I don't know about you, but when my bank statement is different from the usual amount I do check my salary statement. ;)

Comment: A quick search shows that a 3 year statute of limitation seems to be commonly enforced (meaning if they want their money back after more than 3 years, you would be clear, but after a shorter time, you're obliged to pay it back).

Comment: Just for the record: I strongly object to closing this as "company-specific" - this happens regularly (mistakes happen), and there are both clear regulations and common ways of handling this, independent of company.

Comment: And, also for the record: Your manager was extremely foolish and unprofessional when you asked about the money and he said that it was "ok". He should have passed the question on to accounting or HR and have them thoroughly check the numbers - that is their job, after all. Hopefully, he learned his lesson too.

Comment: So the guy who told you "It's OK" is the **same** guy who now wants the money back? Did he offer *any* explanation?

Answer (score 9):

If this were a situation with a bank, you would be able to keep the money in most places. However, this is your employers we're talking about.

You ***can*** take the stance that he said it was OK some 2 weeks ago, and that you're not returning the sum, however that will probably get you fired. You could fight them over it in a court of law, and you may even win (which may be difficult because you have no written statement saying you can keep the money).

However, do you want to ruin this relationship with the company?

If not, just give them the money back. It's not a large sum, and it's probably not worth your energy, effort, and - potentially - reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I naturally wouldn't go to court for that. My question was more about what's the common approach for these type of situations. It looks like paying back is the only reasonable solution.

Comment: "Not a large sum" is very depended on the person though. If his car, laundry machine and fridge just broke down and he used the money on repairs/buying new, money could be really tight and 1.7k could potentially be a large sum. Yes, pay back. If not possible in one go, explain the situation and try to strike a deal with your manager for paying a monthly sum.

Comment: If the bank deposit extra monies into your account, they can get it back. There are cases when the bank accidentally spits out extra money at ATM, or even in one case where someone got a large sum in their account. They all had to pay it back and even more so depending on the amount, criminal charges may be brought. If you didn't earn it, don't spend it.

Comment: In the UK, you would definitely not be able to keep the money if this was a bank, and if you didn't return the money when asked, you could be prosecuted.  This is well established law.

Comment: @moo - there have been cases where individuals report a sum being posted to their accounts without their knowledge (someone made a mistake - the bank, or another person). The bank needs to immediately begin the process of tracing back the issue, and taking possession of the money, otherwise they lose their claim to it. They can't change their minds months later and decide that now it's convenient for them to take action. At least not in Canada and Australia, which have a legal system based on the British one.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, same in Germany. There was a case where a man accidentally received 200 million Euro on his account. He wired 10 mio. to another account, the bank asked the money back, and even asked for 12,000€ interest for the 10 mio. he took. He had to return the money (but did not have to pay interest - [article in German](https://www.welt.de/regionales/hamburg/article106253964/15-Stunden-Multi-Millionaer-muss-keine-Zinsen-zahlen.html)).

Comment: @Dan If I find some extra money out of blue in my bank account, I would call the bank. If the sender is the company I work for and the description says "salary", I ask my manager. When my manager says, it happens and it's ok, I assume I earned it and it's ok to spend it.

Comment: I don't think firing OP for not paying it back immediately would be as easy as you imply in Germany. Especially since this happened in December and the OP might be able to argue that they assumed it was Weihnachtsgeld.

Comment: @AndreiROM Could you explain why you think the company would immediately resort to firing? What justification would the company give? And are you talking about a regular termination (respecting the notice period) or an immediate termination? (I'm not saying that pissing off the company like that is a good idea, but directly jumping to a difficult to justify firing seems rather extreme and risky)

Comment: @codesinchaos - I never claimed that not cooperating would get the OP fired immediately. However, I can't imagine that going over well. One way or another the company would likely black list him, and get rid of him at that point.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a lawyer, so I won't comment on the legalities of the situation. However, if you get on well with your boss and with the company then you should try to come to some agreement with them. I don't think the company will be flexible with the amount they get back, but they should be more flexible with the time frame.

In previous instances where I have had to pay money back to an employer (contractually) they have been more than happy to arrange a monthly repayment plan, with the amount usually deducted from my payslip. Figure out how much you could easily afford to pay back each month and get from that how long it would take you to pay off the amount. If you can repay in 3-6 months then I would expect any reasonable company to be able to accommodate that. If it would take you 12 months they might still be reluctantly accepting of that, especially considering the incorrect information your supervisor initially told you.

Answer (score 3):

As gathered through clarification in the comments your salary statement doesn't say anything about this extra money, but your bank statement was increased by 1700€ compared to your usual salary. This means it is a mistake by accounting and must be paid back.

Moreover, if you don't pay it back this is almost certainly illegal as you basically received an extra 1700€ which didn't go through the tax and social security deductions.

Your employer is entitled to ask for renumeration of this overpayment for up to three years.

Spending it all this quickly was a mistake and may put you in a difficult situation. The sum is nothing to sneeze at (pretty much an average monthly salary after deductions). I recommend paying it back as quickly as possible, if you can't afford to do so immediately offer to pay in affordable monthly rates.

If something like this happens again, do not ask your manager, talk directly to someone in accounting. The people there are more likely to know what happened and correct any possible mistake.

Comment: I  disagree with last sentence. It's almost always the right action to ask your manager. If your manager, doesn't know, she needs to investigate or sent you to someone else. Otherwise you'd have to question everything your manager says on anything, which is really not practical. This case is plain and simple: the manager screwed up, not the OP.

Comment: @Hilmar Depends on the role of the manager. Mine are just leads of my department and work themselves on projects. Even if the managers whole responsibility is managing those under them, salary is usually not something you discuss with them, but with accounting. In the OPs situation, you may certainly be right, as his immediate superior is top management and likely has knowledge of salaries, but in many cases your immediate manager doesn't even know what you earn and has nothing to do with your salary or any related problems.

Comment: I agree with Hilmar, the manager is the sole responsible. OP did what he had to do, got verbal approbation from superior and is thus relieved from all responsibility. From the company point-of-view, their manager underestimated the importance of a question and this mistake cost the company $1700.

Comment: @DannyCoulombe Doesn't work like that in Germany, it's not as simple as the company overpaying him. Any salary must go through the mandated deductions for social security and taxes. Any amount of money going past that consituttes illegal labour. Essentially, the company told the state he received x€ salary, but his bank slip says he received x+1700€. This could have serious legal repercussions if not fixed. It's your responsibility to get the right salary and when your salary and bank statement differ, a verbal approbation is not enough.

Comment: @Dulkan: Yes, the question should have gone directly to accounting or HR. Even if the manager knows and even decides salaries, the actual calculation of the payout is quite complicated, what with taxes, other deductions, bonus calculations and so on. Usually only HR/accounting has the know-how and information required to properly check salary calculations.

Comment: This is in Germany. Getting a higher salary in December is not at all unusual.

Comment: @gnasher729 Did you bother to read my answer before commenting? I asked the OP and he said this extra money does not appear on his salary statement. If it were a normal bonus payment, it would appear on his salary statement. I wrote that in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Dulkan You seem to be pretty sure that employer/OP paid no taxes on this extra money - is that verified? And even if that's the case - the issue would lie with the employer since they normally deduct taxes and social security deductions. The employer would likely get into as much trouble as the OP, if not a lot more, for tax evasion.

Comment: @AllTheKingsHorses If taxes were paid it shows up on the salary statement. Any legal payment to your employees must show up on the salary statement. Your net salary on the salary statement and the amount you gain on your bank statement must be identical. Otherwise an error happened. If the employee gets too much money, the employer is entitled to ask for renumeration for up to three years. In the worst case such overpayment could end up with illegal labour charges, which hurt both employer and employee.

Comment: @Dulkan "Otherwise an error happened." Sure, but it's not clear to me where the error happend - in printing the statement or in paying the taxes, or both. And it's very likely not something the employer can use against the employee because they would be implicating mainly themselves. But, of course, it would be used by the state, if they notice.

Comment: @AllTheKingsHorses Your salary statement is the correct one, as that goes through the tax office. The tax office also must be informed, if you plan to pay any sort of bonus like Weihnachtsgeld to an employee. The situation is pretty muddy, currently the employer overpaid the employee by accident. The verbal approbiation of the manager is worthless from a legal point of view, so unless OP informed his manager in writing he has nothing in hand proving he informed the company about the overpayment. The company noticed it and asks him to return the money, they don't implicate themselves this way.

Answer (score -1):

My feeling about this is that if there is a literal record of you being granted the money by your boss, then you should keep it, but if it was just verbal, then you must give it back. In other words, if your boss said it was ok to keep the money:

(1) in writing, or

(2) in an company email (which is presumably backed up)

Then there is proof that the money is yours and you are free to spend it.

If everything is purely verbal, then there is no proof, so you should error on the side of safety and give the money back.

If there is written proof that you could keep the money and they complain, just tell them that you relied on what your boss WROTE and you spent the money already.

Comment: Even if the manager put it in writing, it is not clear-cut. a) The manager may have overstepped his authority by effectively authorizing a bonus payment (which may or may not impact whether the decision is binding on the company, that's a tricky legal area), and b) even if you could fight in court and win, would you want to?

Comment: @sleske If the manager overstepped his authority, that's the company's problem and the manager's problem, not the problem of the employee. As long as the employee could reasonably assume that the manager didn't overstep his authority (which is reasonable for a small amount like this), it is binding.

Comment: @gnasher729: Maybe, maybe not. I'm no lawyer, but I know the details are tricky. For example, if there is a company-wide rule that extra bonuses must be authorized by two managers, and OP knew the rule, then the manager's promise may _not_ bind the company, because OP should have known the promise was invalid. You may be right, but I wouldn't jump to the conclusion.

Comment: @sleske Their rules don't matter. What matters is that the employee could reasonably rely on what they were told and you can reasonably rely on what your manager tells you. That's what a manager is there for.

Comment: "In writing" likely makes no difference, unless the manager lies about what he said.

Answer (score -1):

The company can't just pay you and then claim it was a mistake. If your boss said the payment was Ok (and a higher payment in December is quite common in Germany), then you can assume that a decision was made to pay you more. If they regret that decision, that's not a reason to go back on this. Now if your name is John Smith and Joe Smith was supposed to get a bonus, that might be an honest mistake. But this is your money, so just saying "a mistake was made" is not good enough.

If mistakes were made, you may have to pay back the money, but since it was the company's mistake and not yours, they are responsible that this doesn't cause you any hardship. If you bought your girlfriend an €1800 engagement ring instead of one for €100 because of the unexpected money, your company will have to agree to withhold the money over a longer stretch of time.

In extreme cases, like the company paying you the wrong (but reasonable) salary over a year, you won't have to pay back anything, because that would mean they tricked you into working for less than you could have got elsewhere.